# How To Use Image As A CheckBox in html

Tags: html, css, checkbox, action

I'm involved in making bus booking sites project. I need to use the seats to book.
So, can we replace checkbox with the image. If Possible, please tell me.
Or, if there is any other possibility, please furnish me with ideas.
Thnku.

Comment: is this what you were looking for? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16352864/how-to-display-image-in-place-of-checkbox

Comment: Using google is always a possibility http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3772273/pure-css-checkbox-image-replacement -> http://jsfiddle.net/4huzr/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

offer a simple solution to css [DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yimDC)

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-id" /> <label for="checkbox-id">Some label</label>
```

**CSS**

```
input[type="checkbox"] {
    position: absolute;
    left: -9999px;
}
input[type="checkbox"] + label {
    background: url(http://xandeadx.ru/examples/styling-checkbox/checkbox-sprite.gif) 0 0 no-repeat;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label {
    background-position: 0 -32px;
}
```

Comment: You could just hide the checkbox with `display:none` or `visibility:hidden` instead of using absolute positioning though...couldn't you?

Comment: tried but in most applications it is right decision