# Replacing a checkbox element with icons

Tags: html, css, checkbox, sass

I want to customize the browser checkbox. When the status is checked, the icon `checked.svg` should be displayed instead of checkbox and the icon `unchecked.svg` otherwise.

Here is my code.
HTML:

```
<div class="checkbox-custom">
   <input type="checkbox"/>
      <div class="checkmark">
          <img src="@/assets/images/icons/checkbox/unchecked.svg" class="unchecked"/>
          <img src="@/assets/images/icons/checkbox/checked.svg" class="checked"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

SASS:

```
.checkbox-custom {
    position: absolute;
    width: 28px;
    height: 28px;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;

    // Hide default browser checkbox
    input[type=checkbox] {
                display: none;
            }

   input[type=checkbox] + .checkmark {
        position: absolute;
        left: 3.5px;
        top: 3.5px;
        right: 3.5px;
        bottom: 3.5px;

        display: inline-block;
        cursor: pointer;

        img {
            width: 21px;
            height: 21px;
        }

        .checked {
            display: none;
        }
    }    

    input[type=checkbox]:checked + .checkmark {
        .checked {
            display: block;
        }

        .unchecked {
            display: none;
        }
    }
 }
```

When i click on the checkbox, nothing happens. What could be the error?

Comment: You never click on the checkbox, because it's hidden. You need to make your images labels for that checkbox, so they trigger check/uncheck.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23907405/how-to-use-image-as-a-checkbox-in-html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16352864/how-to-display-image-in-place-of-checkbox

Answer (score 8):

This can be accomplished without any javascript. Clicking the label element toggles the checkbox inside of it, so with some clever css, we can change the display based on the input's checked state.

```css
input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}
.label {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px;
  /* background: url("unchecked.png") no-repeat left center; */ 
  /* padding-left: 15px; */
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + .label {
  background: #f00;
  color: #fff;
  /* background-image: url("checked.png"); */
}
```

```html
<label><input type="checkbox"><span class="label">Check me</span></label>
```

Change the .label styles to use background-image of your choice (and position it to the left of your text).

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/pKM3x/

CSS:

```
.checkbox{
    width: 23px;
    height: 21px;
     background: transparent url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4p2R.png ) no-repeat 0 50%
}
.checked{
    background: transparent url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4p2R.png ) no-repeat 80% 50%
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="checkbox">
</div>
```

JQUERY:

```
$(".checkbox").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('checked')
});
```

This also possible to do with pure JS.

Comment: It works but in a form, you should use input tags to get value when form is sent.